# Trim Records Issue

Tags: sql, oracle, trim

I am selecting from a table where data is stored as nchar. I am adding " before the record and "| after the record. I am using an Oracle database. I am getting white spaces inbetween my records due to the fixed widths. I have removed half of them using a RTrim.

```
Select distinct RTRIM(('"I-'||AA.Field)|| '"|') AS Unique_ID,
RTRIM('"' ||AA.Name)||'"|' AS Name
From Test1 AA, Test2 B
Where AA.ID= B.ID;
```

How can I remove all white spaces inbetween the fields?

Select dump returns

```
 Typ=2 Len=3: c2,2,3d   Typ=96 Len=80:  0,46,0,69,0,6e,0,61,0,6e,0,63,0,65,0,20,0,20,0,20,0,20,0,20,0,20,0,20,0,20,0,20,0,20,0,20,0,20,0,20,0,20,0,20,0,20,0,20,0,20,0,20,0,20,0,20,0,20,0,20,0,20,0,20,0,20,0,20,0,20,0,20,0,20,0,20,0,20,0,20
Typ=2 Len=3: c2,2,42    Typ=96 Len=80: 0,48,0,40,0,57,0,20,0,20,0,20,0,20,0,20,0,20,0,20,0,20,0,20,0,20,0,20,0,20,0,20,0,20,0,20,0,20,0,20,0,20,0,20,0,20,0,20,0,20,0,20,0,20,0,20,0,20,0,20,0,20,0,20,0,20,0,20,0,20,0,20,0,20,0,20,0,20,0,20
Typ=2 Len=3: c2,2,10    Typ=96 Len=80: 0,48,0,75,0,6d,0,61,0,6e,0,20,0,52,0,65,0,73,0,6f,0,75,0,72,0,63,0,65,0,73,0,20,0,20,0,20,0,20,0,20,0,20,0,20,0,20,0,20,0,20,0,20,0,20,0,20,0,20,0,20,0,20,0,20,0,20,0,20,0,20,0,20,0,20,0,20,0,20,0,20
Typ=2 Len=3: c2,2,b Typ=96 Len=80: 0,49,0,6e,0,66,0,6f,0,72,0,6d,0,61,0,74,0,69,0,6f,0,6e,0,20,0,54,0,65,0,63,0,68,0,6e,0,6f,0,6c,0,6f,0,67,0,79,0,20,0,20,0,20,0,20,0,20,0,20,0,20,0,20,0,20,0,20,0,20,0,20,0,20,0,20,0,20,0,20,0,20,0,20
Typ=2 Len=3: c2,2,1f    Typ=96 Len=80: 0,4d,0,61,0,72,0,6b,0,65,0,74,0,69,0,6e,0,67,0,20,0,20,0,20,0,20,0,20,0,20,0,20,0,20,0,20,0,20,0,20,0,20,0,20,0,20,0,20,0,20,0,20,0,20,0,20,0,20,0,20,0,20,0,20,0,20,0,20,0,20,0,20,0,20,0,20,0,20,0,20
Typ=2 Len=3: c2,2,2e    Typ=96 Len=80: 0,4e,0,65,0,77,0,20,0,4c,0,69,0,6e,0,65,0,73,0,20,0,6f,0,66,0,20,0,42,0,75,0,73,0,69,0,6e,0,65,0,73,0,73,0,20,0,20,0,20,0,20,0,20,0,20,0,20,0,20,0,20,0,20,0,20,0,20,0,20,0,20,0,20,0,20,0,20,0,20,0,20
Typ=2 Len=2: c2,2   Typ=96 Len=80: 0,4f,0,70,0,65,0,72,0,61,0,74,0,69,0,6f,0,6e,0,73,0,20,0,20,0,20,0,20,0,20,0,20,0,20,0,20,0,20,0,20,0,20,0,20,0,20,0,20,0,20,0,20,0,20,0,20,0,20,0,20,0,20,0,20,0,20,0,20,0,20,0,20,0,20,0,20,0,20,0,20
Typ=2 Len=3: c2,2,29    Typ=96 Len=80: 0,50,0,72,0,6f,0,64,0,75,0,63,0,74,0,20,0,44,0,65,0,76,0,65,0,6c,0,6f,0,70,0,6d,0,65,0,6e,0,74,0,20,0,26,0,20,0,50,0,72,0,69,0,63,0,69,0,6e,0,67,0,20,0,20,0,20,0,20,0,20,0,20,0,20,0,20,0,20,0,20,0,20
Typ=2 Len=3: c2,2,24    Typ=96 Len=80: 0,53,0,61,0,6c,0,65,0,73,0,20,0,20,0,20,0,20,0,20,0,20,0,20,0,20,0,20,0,20,0,20,0,20,0,20,0,20,0,20,0,20,0,20,0,20,0,20,0,20,0,20,0,20,0,20,0,20,0,20,0,20,0,20,0,20,0,20,0,20,0,20,0,20,0,20,0,20,0,20
Typ=2 Len=3: c2,2,7 Typ=96 Len=80: 0,43,0,75,0,73,0,74,0,6f,0,6d,0,65,0,72,0,20,0,53,0,65,0,72,0,76,0,69,0,63,0,65,0,73,0,20,0,2d,0,20,0,43,0,75,0,73,0,74,0,6f,0,6d,0,65,0,72,0,20,0,53,0,75,0,70,0,70,0,6f,0,72,0,74,0,20,0,20,0,20,0,20
Typ=2 Len=3: c2,2,1a    Typ=96 Len=80: 0,54,0,72,0,61,0,69,0,6e,0,69,0,6e,0,67,0,20,0,20,0,20,0,20,0,20,0,20,0,20,0,20,0,20,0,20,0,20,0,20,0,20,0,20,0,20,0,20,0,20,0,20,0,20,0,20,0,20,0,20,0,20,0,20,0,20,0,20,0,20,0,20,0,20,0,20,0,20,0,20
Typ=2 Len=2: c2,b   Typ=96 Len=80: 0,4c,0,61,0,77,0,72,0,65,0,6e,0,63,0,65,0,20,0,4a,0,61,0,6e,0,65,0,73,0,20,0,28,0,53,0,79,0,73,0,74,0,65,0,6d,0,20,0,44,0,79,0,6e,0,61,0,6d,0,69,0,63,0,73,0,29,0,20,0,20,0,20,0,20,0,20,0,20,0,20,0,20
Typ=2 Len=2: c1,15  Typ=96 Len=80: 0,4c,0,61,0,79,0,61,0,20,0,48,0,65,0,61,0,6c,0,74,0,68,0,63,0,61,0,72,0,65,0,20,0,4c,0,69,0,6d,0,69,0,74,0,65,0,64,0,20,0,20,0,20,0,20,0,20,0,20,0,20,0,20,0,20,0,20,0,20,0,20,0,20,0,20,0,20,0,20,0,20
Typ=2 Len=2: c1,b   Typ=96 Len=80: 0,41,0,76,0,6f,0,6e,0,64,0,68,0,75,0,20,0,4c,0,69,0,6d,0,69,0,74,0,65,0,64,0,20,0,20,0,20,0,20,0,20,0,20,0,20,0,20,0,20,0,20,0,20,0,20,0,20,0,20,0,20,0,20,0,20,0,20,0,20,0,20,0,20,0,20,0,20,0,20,0,20
Typ=2 Len=3: c2,40,29   Typ=96 Len=80: 0,4c,0,69,0,7a,0,20,0,4f,0,27,0,53,0,75,0,6c,0,6c,0,69,0,76,0,61,0,6e,0,20,0,20,0,20,0,20,0,20,0,20,0,20,0,20,0,20,0,20,0,20,0,20,0,20,0,20,0,20,0,20,0,20,0,20,0,20,0,20,0,20,0,20,0,20,0,20,0,20,0,20
Typ=2 Len=2: c1,1f  Typ=96 Len=80: 0,51,0,75,0,69,0,6e,0,6e,0,20,0,48,0,43,0,20,0,53,0,65,0,72,0,76,0,69,0,63,0,65,0,73,0,20,0,4c,0,69,0,6d,0,69,0,74,0,65,0,64,0,20,0,20,0,20,0,20,0,20,0,20,0,20,0,20,0,20,0,20,0,20,0,20,0,20,0,20,0,20
 Typ=2 Len=3: c2,a,64   Typ=96 Len=80: 0,54,0,61,0,78,0,20,0,41,0,75,0,74,0,68,0,6f,0,72,0,69,0,74,0,79,0,20,0,20,0,20,0,20,0,20,0,20,0,20,0,20,0,20,0,20,0,20,0,20,0,20,0,20,0,20,0,20,0,20,0,20,0,20,0,20,0,20,0,20,0,20,0,20,0,20,0,20,0,20
 Typ=2 Len=3: c2,4d,52  Typ=96 Len=80: 0,4b,0,65,0,76,0,69,0,6e,0,20,0,4b,0,65,0,6e,0,74,0,20,0,20,0,20,0,20,0,20,0,20,0,20,0,20,0,20,0,20,0,20,0,20,0,20,0,20,0,20,0,20,0,20,0,20,0,20,0,20,0,20,0,20,0,20,0,20,0,20,0,20,0,20,0,20,0,20,0,20
```

Example Record
|                                   "Ambulance Service"|

Comment: Please add the tables` DDL

Comment: The columns are NCHAR(40)

Comment: Most likely that you have surrounding characters which are not spaces. Please run this `select  dump(Field,16),dump(Name,16)
from    Test1 ` for the "problematic" records

Comment: I have ran that, what should I do with the results?

Comment: Show it in your post

Comment: I've included a sample, I got lots of row back

Comment: The data looks fine. all these `0,20` are spaces.

Comment: We're missing something. Please add the table definition and a "problematic" sample row.

Comment: What do you mean by table definition? I can't paste a sample row as the formatting doesn't seem to work here?

Comment: (1) Create table ...(2) Just copy-paste

Comment: The table is already on the system, I have pasted an example to the question, and tried here. Formatting corrects itself.

Comment: I know the table exists... :-) I want to recreate it so I could reproduce the issue. You can get it using something like that: `select dbms_metadata.get_ddl('TABLE','TEST1','DMARKOVITZ') from dual`

Comment: Is there any particular part that you're looking for? It's a restricted database and I can't paste the full return

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/134086/discussion-between-dudu-markovitz-and-e-mcandrew).

Answer (score 2):

I believe you want:

```
select distinct '"I-' || TRIM(AA.Field) || '"|' AS Unique_ID,
       '"' || TRIM(AA.Name) ||'"|' AS Name
from Test1 AA join
     Test2 B
     on AA.ID = B.ID;
```

`TRIM()` removes spaces at the beginning and end of the string.  You should do this *before* you append the additional characters.

In addition, you should learn to use proper, explicit `join` syntax.  Simple rule:  *Never* use commas in the `FROM` clause.

If you want to remove all spaces, then use `REPLACE()`:

```
select distinct '"I-' || REPLACE(AA.Field, ' ', '') || '"|' AS Unique_ID,
       '"' || REPLACE(AA.Name, ' ', '') ||'"|' AS Name
from Test1 AA join
     Test2 B
     on AA.ID = B.ID;
```

Comment: Nope that didn't do it, getting the same results as with my code

Comment: I'm still getting a blank column between the two

Comment: @E_McAndrew . . . In that case, the "blank" may not be a space.  You can use `replace(aa.field, ' ', '')` to remove all spaces anywhere in the field (or name).

Comment: Thanks, but still no change.